# Thunderbird opens as a tiny blank window

Tags: ubuntu

Every time I open Thunderbird on Ubuntu Lucid it opens as a tiny window (maybe 2px wide by 15px high) in the top left corner of my desktop.  When I expand the window it's just blank.  The behavior started after I restarted the application because every time I sent and email it would open that same blank little window.

I fixed this once by opening the profile manager ($thunderbird -ProfileManager) and recreating my profile.

Does anybody know what could be causing this?  I can't really find anybody else with this issue on Google.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this issue before and the reason was that some other process (or more likely myself by accident using sudo :) had been messing with the file-rights of my profile- / mailbox-files. It seemed that just starting Thunderbird with root-rights can cause this.
Thunderbird couldn't read any information from the profile and behaved the way you described. Don't ask me why ...

The fix was to chown and chmod the profile-dir recursively.

Comment: Somehow another rogue thunderbird process started.  Killall and a restart fixed everything, but I'm going to take your advice so hopefully it stops happening.  Do you suggest chmod 700?

Comment: Can't remember what I did, probably 755 to be sure, but don't know ...

Answer (score 1):

Another cause might be a somehow still running process... No windows, just holding files hostage...

A second process just causes despair. No Message telling file locked, or any hint of an "orphan" thunderbird still running...

ps -la, and voila... kill -9 ,and fixed !!
So this is when keeping secrets ffrom a legitimate user, but reporting waaaayyyyy more back home... Teleespionage^H^H^H^Hmetrics they call it today... Obiously the call this "Normandie..."

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1189785)